# Traveling between US and Canada with expired US passport but valid EU passport

Tags: canada, passports, us-citizens, eu-citizens

I need to travel to Canada from the US ASAP but my US passport is expired. I do have a valid EU passport.

Will I be able to get in and out of the country no problem?

Comment: which country in the EU? Canada has some restrictions on some EU countries.

Comment: Are you returning to the US afterward, or somewhere else?  That might be the more difficult part.

Answer (score 9):

As long as you have proof that you'll be exiting (a bus or plane ticket out of Canada), they should have no problem with you travelling on your EU passport.

[Visa and passport requirements](http://www.worldtravelguide.net/canada/passport-visa):  Visas are not required by nationals referred to in the chart for stays of up to six months, except the following:

- holders of passports endorsed 'British Subjects' (where holder is subject to Control under the Immigration Act, 1971), 'British Protected Persons', 'British Travel Document' and 'British Certificate of Identity';
- nationals of Bulgaria, Czech Republic and Romania; nationals of Lithuania and Poland require a visa if their passport is not biometric;
- those visiting Canada who visit the USA or Saint Pierre and Miquelon during the same visit, and return directly to Canada as visitors within the period authorised on their initial entry (or any extension thereto).

[Visa Required](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Canada): No, except for EU citizens from Bulgaria, Czech Republic, Lithuania without biometric passport, Poland without biometric passport and Romania.  You can stay for up to 6 months.

[Official Canadian Citizenship and Immigration website listing countries that require a visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp).

Answer (score 7):

You will have no trouble entering or leaving Canada on your EU passport (although it may depend on the EU country as to whether you need a visa or not)

Interestingly the place you are most likely to have trouble is returning to the US. US law says "[Most U.S. citizens, including dual nationals, must use a U.S. passport to enter and leave the United States.](http://travel.state.gov/travel/cis_pa_tw/cis/cis_1753.html)".

I would absolutely **make sure you carry a document that proves your US citizenship**, otherwise you are going to get trouble at the US border. EU passport holders are generally admitted on visa waiver for tourist visits, but you will be fingerprinted and have to pay a fee.

The other problem (assuming that you are currently resident in the US) is that when you return to the US you are not coming for a tourist visit - you are coming back to live. You will need to carry something that proves you have the right to reside in the US. Otherwise if they see you have a permanent address in the US, or just ask you why you are coming to the US, but you have no documentation to prove you have the right to live there, you can and will be denied entry. I know people that has happened to.

Comment: But as [Doc points out](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/11741/583), a US citizen can *always* enter the US (as long as they can prove the citizenship)... Dunno what would happen in practice when re-entering—I'd expect at least some delay and questioning.

Comment: So just need to carry the expired US passport too!

Answer (score 3):

[This page](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/security-securite/admiss-eng.html#s1) would seem to indicate that "If you are a citizen of the United States, you do not need a passport to enter Canada." However, I believe that you still need a passport for air travel.

Comment: While it seems you might be able to enter Canada without a passport, you *will* need a passport or [other acceptable document](http://www.getyouhome.gov/) **in order to re-enter the U.S.** on your way back.

Comment: Technically the US can not refuse entry to a US citizen, even without a passport. It will require additional screening in order to prove you are a citizen, and it's not something I would suggest going through by choice - but you will be allowed back into the US.

Comment: @Doc you are correct, technically. What if you can't prove it?

Answer (score 0):

The current document requirements to travel between Canada, the U.S., and Mexico are given here:

- http://www.getyouhome.gov/